# Search within selected category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to alter the search behavior of a WordPress site where the theme doesn't use `searchform.php` at all (it's the Divi theme). I'd rather not employ a plugin to do this as the site has many plugins already.

The default state of the page is to show "all posts from all categories" (/?cat=0) with a category list dropdown generated using `wp_dropdown_categories()` that allows the user to select other categories.

The desired use case is:

1. The user selects a category from a dropdown
2. The browser goes to the selected category's archive
3. The user types a search query into the search box on the category archive with the intent of seeing only posts and pages in that category that contain the search term.

[image]

I figured I could use the `pre_get_posts` hook to do this. So I did the following:

```
function search_by_cat()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $currenturl = add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
        $previousurl = wp_get_referer();
        if ( strpos( $previousurl, '/category/' ) !==false ) { 
            $searchcategoryurl = untrailingslashit( $previousurl ) . $currenturl;
            wp_redirect( $searchcategoryurl );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'search_by_cat');
```

But this just results in `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in the browser. I think it might be because the user is submitting a search that results in the same destination as the referrer. How do I break out of the redirect loop so I can (essentially) redisplay the page of results? Or is my entire approach all wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: The `pre_get_posts` action passes `WP_Query $query` to the supplied callback. You should probably check if `$query->is_main_query()`, but then you can just call `$query->set()` which just takes the same arguments as `get_posts`. If that doesn’t make sense, I can post an example tomorrow when I’m on a real computer

Comment: That would be much appreciated. I'm googling for what to do with `$query->set()` in this particular case and with this code, but I'm not finding anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea from my comments, you'll need to change the CPT and taxonomy types to match your code. Tax queries are a little weird because of the nested array syntax. The comments should hopefully help understand it more.

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    static function (WP_Query $query) {

        // We only want to run on the main search query
        if (!$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
            return;
        }

        // Attempt to get the parameter, or default to 0
        $category_id = (int)($_GET['category_id'] ?? 0);
        if (!$category_id) {
            return;
        }

        // Since we're search by a taxonomy, we probably want to bind it to a type, too
        $query
            ->set(
                'post_type',
                // Change as needed
                'events'
            );
        $query
            ->set(
                'tax_query',
                [
                    // See this for specifics: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters
                    [
                        // Change as needed
                        'taxonomy' => 'event-type',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => [$category_id],
                    ],
                ]
            );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if I'm understanding correctly that what you're saying with the code above is that I don't need the `function search_by_cat() {}` block from my original code? I kept that block but made it empty, and then added your code, but there's no change in the functionality of the search. A search for a term within a selected category simply shows me all results for all categories. But I need just the results for the selected category. Sorry if I'm not making sense. Wish I understood this better.

Comment: The second argument to `add_filter` and `add_action` is a callback, which in PHP can be expressed in many ways, including as an anonymous function like I did, or as a named function as you did. They both are effectively the same, so you can keep yours if you want. Did you update the code to change the CPT and taxonomy slugs to match your code?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I changed the slugs like this: `$query->set('post_type','post');` and `$query->set('tax_query',[['taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'term_id','terms' => [$category_id],],]);` However, nothing is working as intended when I select a category, view it, then search it. The view that gets returned is the results of the keyword search across all categories (/?cat=0) just like before I had any of this code in place. Would like to have just the search results for the selected category and have it "stick" to the category that was selected at the time of the search.